# CakePhp 4: I configured I18n internationalization but the site is still in english

Tags: internationalization, cakephp-4.x

Good night's community,

I trying to use localization tools of cakephp 4 without success.

First, I have my pot and mo files in cake_root/resources/locales/es_AR.
[image]

In my app.php file I have:
[image]

Finally, in my AppController I have...
[image]

Everything looks OK but site is still in english. Can you help me to find my error?

Thanks,

**EDIT**
I have no idea what's going on. I checked my default.po file (under my locale/es_AR folder) and it looks OK.
[image]

But mi app is showing messages in english.
[image]

Does anyone have a lead to follow?

**EDIT 2**
I'm grapping string in __() as you say @Greg Schmidt.
[image]

Comment: Why is your `default.mo` file only 3KB? That seems wrong, unless the `.pot` file only contains 30KB of comments.

Comment: As usual you're right @ndm . I compiled the original .mo file with a lot of unconfirmed entries. I corrected the .mo file and cleaned cache but I still have the app en en_US.

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you're performing the translation in the template. Safe to assume you're using `__('Periods')`, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end it worked. It was a cache problem. Manually deleting the */tmp/cache* folder fixed the problem.

Comment: you shouldn't delete your tmp folder. instead use `bin/cake cache clear _cake_core_` to force cakephp to reload your translations